# Dynamic entry while posting a json body in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, saml-2.0

I been trying to write jmeter load test for a SAML secured web-service. So for i have a http request sampler which gets the access code and stores in a variable named access_code. But the web-service accepts post request in the form:

api.service.edu/api/authentication with body data  as { "code":"${access_code}","redirect_uri":"some site"} .

but whenever I tried running the jmeter , my sampler gives the following error :

Thread Name: Basic App Usage Flow 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-11-07 21:08:50 EST
Load time: 1209
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 1208
Size in bytes: 370
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 324
Body size in bytes: 46
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 500
Response message: Internal Server Error

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/json; charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8

is it because of the way I am parsing the access_code? if so how can I parse a dynamic value via a json post request?.

Answer (score 0):

1. [HTTP Status Code 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) stands for **Internal Server Error**, according to HTTP protocol specification the problem is on the server side as client status codes (i.e. malformed requests) should have HTTP Status code between [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) and 499. So I would recommend checking server-side logs, most probably you will be able to figure out what's wrong from them.
2. It might be the case your `${access_code}` variable is not defined, i.e. the relevant [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) failed to extract it from the previous response. Double check it's value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination
3. It might be the case your `${access_code}` variable contains some special characters which are not allowed in JSON and [must be escaped](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html)

   - **Backspace** is replaced with `\b`
   - **Form feed** is replaced with `\f`
   - **Newline** is replaced with `\n`
   - **Carriage** return is replaced with `\r`
   - **Tab** is replaced with \t
   - **Double quote** is replaced with `\"`
   - **Backslash** is replaced with `\\`

   If your `${access_code}` variable contains any of the above - the resulting JSON will be incorrect. To be on the safe side I would recommend replacing your `${access_code}` variable reference with [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) call

   ```
   ${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(vars.get('access_code')),)}
   ```
4. It might be the case you're not sending a proper [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header so make sure to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type) as the Content-Type

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I found that I am not receiving the access_code from the previous sampler. I am still going to replace the ${access_code} with the groovy function.